# Scroll one page at a time in qemu's compatmonitor

Tags: qemu

qemu's compatmonitor is not scrollable and I was unable to see all output of commands. How can I scroll one page at a time in qemu's compatmonitor like `<command> | more` in bash ?

[qemu's compatmonitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpyP4.png)

Comment: What is your host OS? How are you launching the `qemu` command?

Comment: My host OS is Windows 64bit. command line: @qemu-system-x86_64.exe -usb -usbdevice tablet  -machine q35,accel=whpx -hda ubuntu_server.qcow2 -m 1024 -smp 4

Comment: Since you're launching from the command line, you should be able to append `-monitor stdio` to that command so the monitor will be in the cmd window... and then be able to scroll it there. I haven't used `qemu` in windows enough to know why it's not scrolling, perhaps an issue with `gtk`?